# Electron await function and access to returned data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, electron

I've seen similar questions asked, but still having trouble grasping the concept of Async/await functions and access to main.js within an Electron app.

I have an Electron app with the following files:

main.js ( some of the un-related details missing here )

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const https = require('https')
const axios = require('axios')
const url = require('url')

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    },
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
  });

ipcMain.handle("doSomethingAxios", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/');
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data;
});
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, icpMain, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

let indexBridge = {
  doSomethingAxios: async () => {
    var result = await ipcRenderer.invoke("doSomethingAxios");
    var whattodo = document.getElementById("whattodo");
    whattodo.innerText = result.activity; // This works.
    // Can't access Jquery or other libraries here.


  }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("indexBridge", indexBridge);
```

renderer.js

```
$("#callApi").click(function(){
    window.indexBridge.doSomethingAxios();
    // Can access Jquery libraries here, but can only return promise from this call.
});
```

index.html

```
<button id="callApi">I am bored</button>
<div id="whattodo"></div>
```

This works, and I am able to call the function and populate the results in the div tags within my index.html, but where I get confused, is if I wanted to perform some post processing with the data using Jquery.

In my preload.js, I can do some manipulation of the data with JS, but what if I wanted to use another JS library to modify the data?

For example, let's say that I wanted to use Jquery to modify the data after it is returned. As far as I can tell and have read, I can't include Jquery in my preload.js file. So, it seems all I can do is return the data to the preload.js, and only return a promise to the renderer.js.

Another example if not clear.
Sometimes I like to use the datatables plugin.
After data is populated into the table, with datatables, you need to call the reload() function to reload the table. In a normal web application, I would make an ajax call to a server side script, get the data, then return an ajax response to populate the table and call the reload function.

I guess, i'm just hung up on how to make below function like a ajax call, where I call a function to server side, return the data to calling function, and then have access to JS libraries to manipulate the data. Right now, it seems that I am only able to return data to the preload.js, and if I try to return from the preload.js to the renderer.js, I can only return a promise, and not the actual data.

Any ideas of what general concept I am missing here?

Comment: Only read the first part, but how is jquery being used to modify the data? Typically, the web app (index.html in this case) would use jquery. I'm guessing you aren't able to require jquery because the window is sandboxed by default as per [this PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/30197) which will forbit you from importing third party scripts (in the preload specifically if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Correct. Index.html would be one place I could put the Jquery code, but that is part of the problem.  For example:

$.post( "test.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});

This only calls alert when the data is received. But, I can't use Jquery in the preload.js and I can't get the data back to the index.html ( or the render.js which in linked in index.html). Only back as a promise. 

I can access the data when returned to the preload.js, but can't touch it with Jquery here.

Comment: You typically shouldn't do anything which modifies the DOM in `preload.js`. You can use it to fetch data from the Main process. If your `doSomethingAxios()` would also return a `Promise`, you could use `.then()` on the returned value (if you need to do something with the fetched data) in the Renderer (not `preload.js`) which would only get executed when the Promise is resolved (which behaves much like your JQuery callback example). Take a look at [this tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises).

Comment: This was the answer. Thanks Alexander. The promise returned, can be accessed with the .then() function. I set a variable of the promise return, and then was able to use the .then() function to get the data from the promise. 
promise.then((data) => console.log(data[0].name));
If you post this as the answer, I will accept it as the answer. Thanks!